# I want to detect the user's computer language so that I can translate the page according to it

Tags: python, django, django-views, internationalization

I want the user to enter  the website to see the text translated in his computer's language and this is what I am trying to do but when I change my computer language into Spanish, nothing changes

```
def index(request):

    lang = get_language()
    translation.activate(lang)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Is get language a good function to use here or there is something more accurate?

Comment: Did you setup translating according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)?

Comment: yes, I did and when I force lang  = "es" translation works but I want him to detect the user's machine language @wfehr